# ASP.NET Core 2 XML Configuration File Loading/Injection

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings

I'm having fits trying to get an XML configuration file loaded in ASP.NET Core 2. I prefer XML because I have CDATA, and I don't want to encode in JSon.

Generally speaking the structure looks like this (I've left some elements/attributes out for clarity):

```
<MyConfiguration>
    <MyConnectors>
      <MyConnector name="abc" ... other attributes>
        <ElementA> ... <ElementA>
        <ElementB> ... <ElementB>
      </MyConnector>
    <MyConnectors>
</MyConfiguration>
```

I also have the necessary classes to represent the configuration and can successfully deserialize the configuration if I do it manually using

```
... XmlSerializer(typeof(MyConfiguration)).Deserialize(xmlStream) ...
```

Inside Program.cs I've added the XML file using

```
config.AddXmlFile(...)
```

and in Startup.cs I do

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration"));
```

I've tried a number of variations for what I pass into ...GetSection and I've played around with XML, all to no avail. If I switch to JSon and put a portion of the configuration in there for testing ... no problem.